# Angular Material mat sidenav content cause big gap margin

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was creating responsive Mat Tool with Mat Sidenav but after that there is a big gap when I put the sidenav container, and it force my main content to be at bottom of the page since the container just place the blank screen

[image]
[image]

I already tried to put fullscreen in the mat sidenav container, using margin

```
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>

<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>horizontal_split</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
      <span><strong><a routerLink="home" class="number1">infor</a><a routerLink="home">sys</a></strong></span>

      <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">

          <div class="tes">
          <button mat-button routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active"><b>About</b></button>
          <button mat-button routerLink="sofi" routerLinkActive="active"><b>SOFI</b></button>
          <button mat-button routerLink="pisi" routerLinkActive="active"><b>PISI</b></button>
          <button mat-button routerLink="dokuku" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Dokuku</b></button>
          <button mat-button routerLink="customers" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Customers</b></button>
          <button mat-button routerLink="career" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Career</b></button>
        </div>
      </div>


    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill>
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav fxLayout="column">
        <div fxLayout="column">
          <button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" mat-button>Close</button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active"><b>About</b></button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="sofi" routerLinkActive="active"><b>SOFI</b></button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="pisi" routerLinkActive="active"><b>PISI</b></button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="dokuku" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Dokuku</b></button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="customers" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Customers</b></button>
          <button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" routerLink="career" routerLinkActive="active"><b>Career</b></button>
        </div>
      </mat-sidenav>

    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

I just want to ask for some help with the problem of this unnecessary blank page and make the picture from the bottom to be able to connect with the Mat Tool